# Form's input type="submit" does not seem to trigger the onsubmit handler

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onsubmit

I am attempting to trigger a javascript function via onsubmit to validate my form.

I know that the function itself works because I can call it within script tags immediately after the form's markup and I receive my console.log message and the error messages it creates appear on the form.

The PHP validation itself works, but I've only been able to actually submit the form via javascript's `.submit` placed upon a div. Obviously because this bypasses any client-side validation, I can't leave it that way, thus I've replaced my `div id="submit"` with an `input type="submit"`.

I've been looking at other examples, including forms I've coded myself in the past that I know work, and seem completely out of answers. This is probably insanely easy, and for some reason, I just can't and haven't been able to see it for the last 6 hours. o_O

Here is my form's markup:

```
<form name="emailus" id="emailus" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <a href="mailto:example@email.com">
        <h3><i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-large"></i>Send us an email<span>: example@email.com</span></h3>
    </a>

    <div class="half">
        <fieldset class="name">
            <label for="cf_name"><h4>Name <span>*</span></h4></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_name" class="textualformfield" alt="Jane Doe" pattern="^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="emailaddress">
            <label for="cf_email"><h4>E-mail <span>*</span></h4></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_email" class="textualformfield" alt="janedoe@email.com" pattern="{long string of regex}">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="phonenumber">
            <label for="cf_phonenumber"><h4>Phone</h4></label>
            <input type="tel" name="cf_phonenumber" class="textualformfield" alt="555-555-5555">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="eventdate">
            <label for="cf_eventdate"><h4>Event Date</h4></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_eventdate" class="textualformfield" alt="May 25th, 2012">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="location">
            <label for="cf_location"><h4>Location</h4></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_location" class="textualformfield" alt="The Church">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
        <textarea name="cf_message" class="textualformfield" alt="Your Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" for="emailus" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've attempted several different iterations of `onsubmit="return validateForm();"`—with or without the semicolon, writing it as `onSubmit` or `onsubmit`... I don't know. I can't see what's wrong with this at all. Anyone?

Below is the function to be called `onsubmit`, `validateForm`. It is located in another file, but the file is always included when the form is, and I've made sure this function is not within `$(document).ready` and is available globally as I've called it from within script tags directly following the form.

```
var validateForm = function() {
    var valid = true;

    jQuery('p.validationhelpers').remove();

    if (document.emailus.cf_email.value == "" || document.emailus.cf_email.value == "janedoe@email.com") {
        jQuery('.emailaddress').append("<p class='validationhelpers'>Please enter an email address.</p>");
        jQuery('.emailaddress>input').focus();
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.emailus.cf_name.value == "" || document.emailus.cf_name.value == "Jane Doe") {
        jQuery('.name').append("<p class='validationhelpers'>Please enter your name.</p>");
        jQuery('.name>input').focus();
        valid = false;
    }
    console.log("I was triggered");

    return valid;
}
```

Edit 2: Added PHP Validation/Post code:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST) ) { 
    $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
    $field_phone = $_POST['cf_phonenumber'];
    $field_eventdate = $_POST['cf_eventdate'];
    $field_location = $_POST['cf_location'];
    $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

    $mail_to = 'example@email.com';

    //final attempt at validation or email submission preventation
    if ($field_name == "Jane Doe" || empty($field_name) || $field_email == "janedoe@email.com" || empty($field_email)) {
        return false;
    }


    if (!($field_eventdate == "May 25th, 2012") && !empty($field_eventdate) && !($field_name == "Jane Doe") && !empty($field_name)) {
        $subject = 'Request for '.$field_date. ' from '.$field_name . 'via thiswebsite.com';
    } else {
        $subject = $field_name . ' has contacted you via thiswebsite.com';
    }

    if (!($field_name == "Jane Doe") && !empty($field_name)) {
        $body_message = 'Client\'s Name: '.$field_name."\n\n";
    }
    if (!($field_email == "janedoe@email.com") && !empty($field_email)) {
        $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n\n";
    }
    if (!($field_phone == "555-555-5555") && !empty($field_phone)) {
        $body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n\n";
    }
    if (!($field_eventdate == "May 25th, 2012") && !empty($field_eventdate)) {
        $body_message .= 'Event Date: '.$field_eventdate."\n\n";
    }
    if (!($field_location == "The Church") && !empty($field_location)) {
        $body_message .= 'Location: '.$field_location."\n\n";
    }
    if (!($field_message == "Your Message") && !empty($field_message)) {
        $body_message .= 'Message: '. "\n".$field_message;
    }

    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    $body_message = stripslashes($body_message);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('#contactus').before("<hr class='confirmationhelpers'><p class='confirmationhelpers'>Your e-mail has been sent!<br/>Thank you! We'll contact you shortly.</p><hr class='confirmationhelpers'>");
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                alert('It seems there\'s been an error. Please, send an email to example@email.com to request your appointment.');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Just to be clear—when I click the Submit button, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: could you post your on submit()

Comment: Try and remove the use of `return` on the `onsubmit` value, and simply put `validateForm()`, or, better yet: `validateForm(); return false;` in case the former does not return a truthy or falsy value. By the way, what's the use of `for` on the submit input?

Comment: ensure that your validateForm() return true on successful validation

Comment: first of all remove the for attribute in the input[type=submit], checking the javascript code should be next step, but make sure there isn't any javascript command preventing the submission since you are expecting a submission.

Comment: @javapirate is the `validateForm` function what you meant for me to post? Or are you referring to the PHP's portion?

Comment: @EliranMalka Hmm... tried those just now to no avail. The `for` wasn't for anything. It was a product of my attempts to troubleshoot this when I was thinking "is it not ... linking to the form or something?" It's gone now, as per your and @w3jimmy's recommendations.

Comment: where the control is skipping

Comment: @PSR [A link to the site so that you can see exactly what's going on? Sure. Click right here](http://ronparksphotography.com/weddings), then click Contact.

Comment: @aminimalanimal   what happens when you do this: `onsubmit='return true;'` or without having the onsubmit handler itself

Comment: @javapirate Nothing, in both cases. Guess its time to take a look at the PHP portion of my validation, huh? Adding now...

Comment: yes php code may hold the key. Hope you dont have any js errors in the console. Have a look on it.

Comment: @javapirate Only a facebook integration-related error, but it hasn't affected anything other than the debug console (that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery is blocking the form submit here:

```
//this hides the contact form if the overlay is clicked. children is there to prevent the children from also having this effect.
    $('.overlay_vertical_align').click(function() {
        $('.grey_overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    }).children().click(function(e) {
        return false;
    });
```

I mean, when I debug your site, and press the submit button, I reach the `return false;` above, after which the event processing is over.

Comment: Also, it **must** be `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` if you want your validateForm function to be able to prevent invalid forms from being submitted.

Comment: You sir, win the prize.

May I ask how you debugged it down to that level? What browser or tool you're using? Thank you for getting me on the right track.

Comment: @aminimalanimal I used Chrome's Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), the script debugger is on the 'Sources' view.  I marginally prefer Internet Explorer's Developer Tools (F12) to step-debug JavaScript code, but in this case the page would not even load (IE8/XP) - besides it's handy to be able to debug script in every browser.  So I paused all script execution, then clicked the submit button, and stepped through the code (the jQuery internals are not easy to follow, so I just pressed step-into until I finally arrived at your code).

Comment: Very cool. I hadn't figured out how to use that pane yet. And yeah... figuring out what's going on with IE is the task I get to fix after this one. O_o (Though I'm guessing it's got something to do with the boilerplate I used.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing happens is that you use the new html5 'pattern' attribute which tries to regex validate your input before it even reaches your validate function. Remove the pattern attribute and try again.

Comment: Hmm... Good guess, but I've just removed it and that doesn't seem to be the case. I've also successfully used the `pattern` attribute alongside javascript validation before and it hasn't seemed to get in the way, though I do remember it taking precedent at some point.